# "Parameterising" extensions $0\to E\to W\to F\to 0$ by $\mathbb P(H^1(E\otimes F^*))$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex projective manifold and $E$ and $F$ be holomorphic vector bundles on $X$. The extensions of $F$ by $E$ are classified by elements $e\in  H^1(E\otimes F^*)$. On the other hand, for any non-zero $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ the extension bundles corresponding to classes $e$ and $\alpha e$ are isomorphic.

**Main question.** Is is possible to construct a universal extension triple 
$$0\to {\cal E}\to {\cal W}\to {\cal F}\to 0$$ 
over $\mathbb P(H^1(E\otimes F^*))\times X$ such that for any $0\ne e\in H^1(E\otimes F^*)$ the restriction of $0\to \cal E\to \cal W\to \cal F\to 0$ to $[e]\times X$ was  the extension of $F$ by  $E$ corresponding to $[e]$.

**Question 2.** If such a universal family exists, what can one say about the family of restriction bundles $\cal E_x, \cal W_x, \cal F_x$ over $\mathbb P(H^1(E\otimes F^*))\times x$ parametrized by points of $X$. For example, what are their Chern classes?

Comment: I think you might be interested in the first section of the article by Mireille Martin-Deschamps, "Propriétés de descente des variétés à fibré cotangent ample, Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) 34 (1984), no. 3, 39–64.

Comment: In the case  when X is a curve and E and F are line bundles, this, and a lot more,  was done by Bertram.  He was trying to construct a morphism from the (appropriate) blow up of $ \mathbb P(H^1(E^*\otimes F))\times " to the moduli of rk 2 vb's.  You could have a look and see to what extent his construction of the universal bundle generalizes to your case.  The paper is called "Moduli of Rank Two Vector Bundles,..... "

Comment: Same comment as above, but with the second 'dollar sign' so math comes out :) .  In the case when X is a curve and E and F are line bundles, this, and a lot more, was done by Bertram. He was trying to construct a morphism from the (appropriate) blow up of $ \mathbb P(H^1(E^*\otimes F^{*}))$ " to the moduli of rk 2 vb's. You could have a look and see to what extent his construction of the universal bundle generalizes to your case. The paper is called "Moduli of Rank Two Vector Bundles,..... "

Comment: See also Example 2.1.12 in Huybrechts-Lehn's "The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves" (the 1997 edition).

Comment: Pgraf, many thanks! This answers my question completely.